# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{2n-1} \sqrt{n} \frac{ \Gamma(n)^{2}}{\Gamma(2n)} = \sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

How does one prove this identity: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{2n-1} \sqrt{n} \frac{ \Gamma(n)^{2}}{\Gamma(2n)} = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Taken from *Gamelin : Complex Analysis*

Comment: Use the duplication formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

[image]

which can be shown by considering $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^n x$ (as Wallis originally did) or using the product expansion for $\sin x$:

$\displaystyle \sin x = x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$ and setting $\displaystyle x=\pi/2$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram|Alpha shows an [expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+goes+to+infinity+of+%28+%28power%282%2C2n-1%29%29+%28sqrt%28n%29%29+%28power%28gamma%28n%29%2C2%29+%2F+gamma%282n%29%29+%29).